# NiFi: Hbase controller service restart

Tags: apache-nifi

NiFi version used is 1.11.4.
I am using FetchHbaseRow and PutHbaseJson and have configured Hbase controller service succesfully.

since we have migrated from onpremise to AWS NiFi. the FetchHbaseRow and PutHbaseJson processors are throwing error.

The below image shows the error for FetchHbaseRow processor. It occurs frequently atleast once per day.
[image]
whenever this issue occurs, i have rectified by restarting the controller service.
the below shows the controller service for Hbase.
[image]

[image]

But i could not find the root cause how it worked by restarting the controller service. any explanation please.

Comment: Please edit the question and add errors you have before restart

Comment: @daggett thanks for your response. i have attached some screenshot for your perusal. Please check if it helps.

Comment: seems IO/connection error. maybe it tries to start before network appears. have you tried  to increase `HBase Client Retries` ?

Comment: i haven't tried to increase. how can we cross verify if we are increasing the retry number. in my case, i found that this issue occurs atleast 2 to 5 times a day.

Comment: You have in your error `failed after attempts=1`

Comment: Ok i will try to increase the retry and keep you posted. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: i found the issue which was kerberos authentication getting expired every 24 hours. this is the reason i need to restart hbase controller service. we are working on with cloudera team to extend the authentication. thanks for your support.